# Is a function that preserves normal subgroups a group morphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Proposition 2.10.4 in Michael Artin's *Algebra* says that the inverse image of a normal subgroup under a group morphism is a normal subgroup (of the morphism's domain, of course)

Motivated by analogy with topology, my question is then if the converse implication holds: given a function between groups such that inverse images of normal subgroups are always normal, is such a function in fact a group morphism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and here is a silly reason: there are many groups whose only normal subgroups are the trivial group $\{1\}$ and the entire group! Such groups are called *simple*. Basic examples include the cyclic groups $C_p$ for primes $p$, and the alternating groups $A_n$ for $n \neq 4$. If you take any two big simple groups $G, G'$, and any mapping $f: G \to G'$ such that $f(a) = 1 \iff a = 1$, then $f$ will satisfy your requirements. Obviously $f$ can still be a very weird function then; certainly it will not need to be a group homomorphism.

Comment: @CMonsour, no, this is not necessary. Note that we are talking about *inverse images* under $f$, not images. So e.g. the mapping $f: A_5 \to A_5$ defined by $f(\mathrm{id}) = \mathrm{id}$ and $f(\alpha) = (1\, 2)$ when $\alpha \neq \mathrm{id}$ is an example.